# Comparing elements from a string to rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have rows in a dataframe that I would like to select if they contains numbers/numerical values which are included in the following string.

```
text_1="source="The previous low was 27,523. The 1.35 trillion ($22.5 million ) program could start in October. The number of people who left the country plunged 99.8 percent from a year earlier to 2,750, according to the data from the agency."
```

Dataframe

```
Account       Sentences
51343     The subsidies are expected to form part of a second budget. 
6376     The subsidies, totalling 2.35tn, are expected to form part of a second budget. New plans to allocate $22.5 billion to a new reimbursement programme.

31     The subsidies, totalling 1.35tn, are expected to form part of a second budget. New plans to allocate $22.5 billion to a new reimbursement programme.

2624     The way to a sports fan’s heart? Behind-the-scenes content from their favourite teams.
613    The subsidies, totalling 1.43 tn, are expected to form part of a second budget. New plans to allocate $21.5 billion to a new reimbursement programme.

764    The subsidies, totalling 1.35tn, are expected to form part of a second budget. New plans to allocate $22.5 billion to a new reimbursement programme.
```

Desired output would be to create three columns:

- one including all numbers that match with a row
- one including all numbers that differ with those from text
- one for boolean values (1 for matching all values; 0 if they do not match at all; 0.5 if there is at least one value in common).

The first thing that I was trying to do was to change all commas in full stops to avoid confusion in numbers in both `text` and `Sentences` column's rows. 
Then, extracting all numbers from `text` in order to compare with each numerical value in rows.

```
numb=(re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", text))
for i in df['Sentences']:
        print(re.findall("\d+[,.\d]\d+", i))
```

Numbers to compare for each row in Sentences are: `27.523, 1.35, 22.5, 2.750, 99.8` (please notice that the comma should be converted in full stop).

Now, I should create the new columns with the findings to have

```
Account       Common                       Difference                    Match?
51343                            { 27.523, 1.35, 22.5, 2.750, 99.8 }       0
6376           22.5                          2.35                         0.5

31        {1.35, 22.5}              { 27.523, 2.750, 99.8 }               0.5

2624                             { 27.523, 1.35, 22.5, 2.750, 99.8 }       0
613                    { 27.523, 1.35, 22.5, 2.750, 99.8 }, {1.43, 21.5}   0

764       {1.35, 22.5}           { 27.523, 2.750, 99.8 }                  0.5
```

Do you think it could be something doable? could you give me any advice to get these results?

Comment: have you looked into `str.extractall` ? try `df['Sentences'].str.extractall('(\d+[,.\d]\d+)')`

Comment: The problem, I think, is in converting number to the same format. For example, I have 27.523 in text and 27,523 in Sentences. They should be the same, but in a different format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
# define variables
regex = r"(\d+[\.|,]?\d*)"
numbers = { "27.523", "1.35", "22.5", "2.750", "99.8" }




# define needed functions
def normalize(numbers):
    # converts , in numbers to .
    normalized = set()
    for number in numbers:
        normalized.add(re.sub(',', '.', number))
    return normalized

def get_difference(text):
    found_numbers = set(re.findall(regex, text))
    found_numbers = normalize(found_numbers)
    return found_numbers.difference(numbers)

def get_common(text):
    found_numbers = set(re.findall(regex, text))
    found_numbers = normalize(found_numbers)
    return found_numbers.intersection(numbers)

def get_match_ratio(text):
    found_numbers = set(re.findall(regex, text))
    found_numbers = normalize(found_numbers)
    common = found_numbers.intersection(numbers)
    if len(common) == len(numbers):
        return 1
    elif len(common) > 0:
        return 0.5
    else:
        return 0

# apply the functions and generate new columns
df["Common"] = df["Sentences"].apply(get_common)
df["Difference"] = df["Sentences"].apply(get_difference)
df["Match?"] = df["Sentences"].apply(get_match_ratio)
df.drop(columns=["Sentences"], inplace=True)
print(df.to_string())
#   Account        Common    Difference  Match?
#0    51343            {}            {}     0.0
#1     6376        {22.5}        {2.35}     0.5
#2       31  {1.35, 22.5}            {}     0.5
#3     2624            {}            {}     0.0
#4      613            {}  {21.5, 1.43}     0.0
#5      764  {1.35, 22.5}            {}     0.5
```

According to the `Difference` column. I don't know how you got these values. So, I improvised trying to guess what could work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Anwarvic. Do you know how I could convert numbers to the same format (also for rows)? I am doing it manually for text, but I cannot do manually for all the rows (thousands). The problem is that some numbers in text use commas while the same in rows use full stop. For example: 27,523 and 27.523 are the same numbers. In this way I should get more values in common, rather than different (not matching)

Comment: I've edited my answer... I did exactly that using the function `normalize`

Comment: Sorry, @Anwarvic, I am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection' `. This does not happen using your previous answer

Comment: oops... ifxed it. Could you try again?